# How do I use variables from outside in my function?

Tags: php, function, laravel

I saw some other user here asking this and I tried what they said in the answer section, but nothing had worked for me.

I have this variable:

```
$inputs = \Request::all();
$domain = $inputs['domain'];
```

Now in $domain is the domain-name I need.

This is my function:

```
function searchfor ($search)
{
    $path = '/var/www/laravel/logs/vhosts/';
    $shell_exec = shell_exec("grep -c -i $search  $path" . $domain . ".log");
    return $shell_exec;
}
```

This haven't worked cause of course PHP doesn't know what `$domain` is.

Now I tried put a  `global $domain;` in the function but this haven't worked either.

I also tried this:

```
function anzahlsuche($search) use ($domain) { ... }
```

But it's the same, it doesn't worked for me.

Does somebody have another idea what I can do?

I'm using the Laravel Framework, maybe someone knows a solution in laravel, normal php would do it too, of course.

Comment: add `$domain` as a second parameter to your `anzahlsuche()` function

Comment: and use global $domain; too?

Comment: no : `function searchfor ($search)` becomes `function searchfor ($search, $domain)`

Comment: the best way, I think, is to format function as `function searchfor( $search, $domain )`. BTW, I don't understand why `global $domain;` doesn't work.

Comment: well I will try - give me a sec

Comment: okay worked for me! thanks, haven't seen that I also can put it in the function paramters! thanks a lot!

Comment: Ignoring the actual question, what you're doing here is a huge security hole. You're taking input from a user and using it inside a shell command, and without even escaping it. That's a big no-no.

Comment: well the input isn't from a user - there isn't a textbox where the user writes his domain-name. the domain-name comes from my database.

Comment: but can you give me an advice how do I can do it more save?

Comment: like how do I explace the $domain variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

two options - pass the variable as a parameter to the function or use the global expression to name the variable within the function. The variable must be available in the scope that the function is called.

```
 $inputs = \Request::all();
 $domain = $inputs['domain'];

 function anzahlsuche($search,$domain)
        {
            $path = '/var/www/laravel/logs/vhosts/';
            $shell_exec = shell_exec("grep -c -i $search  $path" . $domain . ".log");
            return $shell_exec;
        }

 function anzahlsuche($search)
        {
            global $domain;
            $path = '/var/www/laravel/logs/vhosts/';
            $shell_exec = shell_exec("grep -c -i $search  $path" . $domain . ".log");
            return $shell_exec;
        }
```

Comment: There is also a third option, that is to create an anonymous function so that you can use the `use($var)` syntax. This is usually considered as a bad practice though, as you don't create anonymous functions when you can create a normal function.

Comment: first way worked perfect! thanks!

Comment: seccond one havent.. I dont know why, but I'll take the first one :)